# Explain python slicing issue

Tags: python

As we know

```
seq[::stride] = [seq[0],   seq[stride],     ..., seq[-1] ]
```

But when stride become negative then

```
seq[::stride] =[seq[-stride], seq[-2*stride], . . . . ]
```

Why is the latter case not like `[seq[0],seq[-stride], . . . . ]` ?

Answer (score 3):

Because if the stride is negative, the slice always automatically starts from the end and goes backwards.